# What is the correct url to file mapping for Polymer-CLI application

Tags: polymer

I have an existing (half developed) polymer(client)/nodejs(server) application which is using http/2. I am interested in adjusting its existing structure so I can use polymer-cli to, in particular, produce the build/unbundled directory. To see what directories `polymer init` would create I have used it to create a dummy app-drawer-template application.  I plan to tweak my directory (and complete app-shell etc) structure for my existing app to follow what this sample app is telling me.

However I am getting totally confused with the documentation as to the proper directory layouts to make it happen.  In particular, two particular things confuse me.

1. it says the page views should be stored in `src/my-view/my-view.html` directory, but that app it actually built when I did `polymer init app-drawer-template` stored the view in `src/my-view.html` (which I happen to like better as I can probably handle up to 50 or so elements before I need to start adding subdirectories)
2. It says the server should map both `bower_components/`and `src/` directories to the `/components` url, yet again, the components generated actually link to polymer in the html import as `../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html` making such complications

The other thing that is confusing me is what has happened to the node-module parts of web-component-tester.  In my previous iteration I have both `bower_components` and `node_modules` needed for the client, and because I also have node-modules for the server, I created them at a project root level of my application (with the client in the `app/` directory, and my server spread out over several directories off of project root).  My sample app-drawer-template app has no node modules at all, and since I use nvm for managing my node versions, I have node version 6.0.2 with only bower and polymer-cli installed globally and the only other pre-requisite that seems to have been installed is mocha.  Yet `polymer test` runs web component tester and I can see it starting up selenium etc.

Final question - is it possible to control polymer-cli to only produce the unbundled version of the build.  I will be serving it via http/2 and because its an inhouse application can control which browsers can use it.

Comment: There are really 3 questions here, which makes it difficult to provide an answer. Splitting them up would increase the chances of getting an answer to each one.